# Spring Cloud Data Flow: deploy stream defined with Java DSL

Tags: spring, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-dataflow

I'm using Spring Cloud Data Flow.

Is there any way to deploy a stream defined with the Java DSL providing the .jar uri instead of executing it as a client?

I want to threat it like the applications I can register (e.g. log-sink) because in fact is an application.

Thanks!

Comment: SCDF does provide a DSL - https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#spring-cloud-dataflow-stream-intro-dsl

Comment: I know that, but I'm looking for a way to define it using java DSL and then provide the jar with that definition to create the stream in SCDF.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Java DSL (which implements the Spring Cloud Data Flow REST client). For documentation on using Java DSL, you can refer to the documentation [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#spring-cloud-dataflow-stream-java-dsl).

Comment: Hi! From the title of the question and also the body is obvious that I already know that there is a Java DSL. That was not the question. Im looking to provide a .jar reference instead of running a code.